# Parse .then method and chaining | Syntax eludes me | TypeError error (ParseCDN)

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform, typeerror, chaining

Previous post: [Parse .then method and chaining | Syntax eludes me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977141/parse-then-method-and-chaining-syntax-eludes-me)

My original question was well answered by Nath. However I'm currently experiencing a TypeError which I am yet unable to resolve.

TypeError message:

```
TypeError: e is undefined


...arse.Object");return{__type:"Pointer",className:this.className,obj
```

My current code (updated 2014-08-14 18:44):

```
function harness(){
    try{
        console.log("harness function");

        Parse.initialize("*key1*", "*key2*"); //Note: I do have the keys set properly

        var query = new Parse.Query("Users");

        var userEmail = app.getValue("txtEmail");   
        console.log("userEmail: "+userEmail); 
        //Note: Using Application Craft hence the use of 'app.getValue' and other custom JS functions

        query.equalTo("email", userEmail);  console.log(query);

        query.find().then(
            function(results) {    
                    console.log("Within the Then!");
                    console.log(results); 
                    return query.find();
                },                
                function(error){
                    console.log("Could be an error"+error);
                    return;
                }

        );

        console.log("END harness function");
    }
    catch(err){
        errorHandler("harness ERROR", err.message);
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Having read various forum posts I've investigated the stack trace and given the variable 'e' am fairly certain it's the ParseCDN I'm not calling correctly. I suspect my inexperience with returning promises is the source of the issue (tried to follow Nath's advice). The commented code block at the top was one of my variations of a promise to be returned; having read through the Parse API Docs it seemed that .then inherently returned a promise anyway so 'settled' on simply returning my results, and then the queryObject again (per their samples).

The DOM upon error is interesting because it lists find(e) as a method, yet not then(). Not sure if I'm referring to an outdated js library perhaps (don't think so).

If anyone can assist, or potentially expand upon Nath's work so far (copy below) I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks
-James

*Amended code snippet from Nath*

```
query.find().then(function(result){
  doSomethingAsync(); //must return a promise for chaining to work!
}).then(null,function(error){
  // an alternative way to handle errors
  //handles errors for all chained promises.
})
```

Comment: Show the code that created and configures the `query` object, as I suspect that might be the problem.

Comment: ^^ Could you post the entire code.

Comment: Could you specifically post the code where e is first referenced and some context to that line.

Comment: ...and your then clause is returning the same query as triggers it. That probably isn't going to crash but it is redundant.

Comment: Post updated with complete function code including query object, my error handler (catching the 'e' issue), and my slipshod .then() usage. Thanks for helping!